# How to find inherited tables programatically in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have a PostgreSQL 8.3 database where table inheritance is being used. I would like to get a list of all tables along with its schema name which is inherited from a base table using query. Is there any way we can get this using PGSQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you're on such an old version of PostgreSQL you'll probably have to use a PL/PgSQL function to handle inheritance depths of > 1. On modern PostgreSQL (or even 8.4) you'd use a recursive common table expression (`WITH RECURSIVE`).

The `pg_catalog.pg_inherits` table is the key. Given:

```
create table pp( );     -- The parent we'll search for
CREATE TABLE notpp(); -- Another root for multiple inheritance
create table cc( ) inherits (pp); -- a 1st level child of pp
create table dd( ) inherits (cc,notpp); -- a 2nd level child of pp that also inherits aa
create table notshown( ) inherits (notpp); -- Table that inherits only notpp
create table ccdd () inherits (cc,dd) -- Inheritance is a graph not a tree; join node
```

A correct result will find `cc`, `dd`, and `ccdd`, but not find `notpp` or `notshown`.

A single-depth query is:

```
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname, pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits 
  INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ON (pg_inherits.inhrelid = pg_class.oid) 
  INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid) 
WHERE inhparent = 'pp'::regclass;
```

... but this will only find `cc`.

For multi-depth inheritance (ie `tableC` inherits `tableB` inherits `tableA`) you have to extend that via a recursive CTE or a loop in PL/PgSQL, using  the children of the last loop as parents in the next.

**Update**: Here's an 8.3 compatible version that should recursively find all tables that inherit directly or indirectly from a given parent. If multiple inheritance is used, it should find any table that has the target table as one of its parents at any point along the tree.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_children(oid) RETURNS SETOF oid as $$
SELECT i.inhrelid FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits i WHERE i.inhparent = $1
UNION
SELECT find_children(i.inhrelid) FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits i WHERE i.inhparent = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_children_of(parentoid IN regclass, schemaname OUT name, tablename OUT name) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname, pg_class.relname 
        FROM find_children($1) inh(inhrelid) 
          INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ON (inh.inhrelid = pg_class.oid) 
          INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid);
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STABLE;
```

Usage:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM find_children_of('pp'::regclass);
 schemaname | tablename 
------------+-----------
 public     | cc
 public     | dd
 public     | ccdd
(3 rows)
```

Here's the recursive CTE version, which will work if you update Pg, but won't work on your current version. It's much cleaner IMO.

```
WITH RECURSIVE inh AS (
        SELECT i.inhrelid FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits i WHERE inhparent = 'pp'::regclass
        UNION
        SELECT i.inhrelid FROM inh INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_inherits i ON (inh.inhrelid = i.inhparent)
)
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname, pg_class.relname 
    FROM inh 
      INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class ON (inh.inhrelid = pg_class.oid) 
      INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON (pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning multiple inheritance. I didn't think of that.

Comment: This is great query. I just tried executing it and it worked perfect!! I modified this to accommodate our naming conventions. Thanks a lot for this...

Answer (score 2):

The following statement retrieves all child tables of the table `public.base_table_name`:

```
select bt.relname as table_name, bns.nspname as table_schema 
from pg_class ct 
    join pg_namespace cns on ct.relnamespace = cns.oid and cns.nspname = 'public' 
    join pg_inherits i on i.inhparent = ct.oid and ct.relname = 'base_table_name' 
    join pg_class bt on i.inhrelid = bt.oid 
    join pg_namespace bns on bt.relnamespace = bns.oid
```

It should work with 8.3 although I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @CraigRinger, Thanks for that input, could you please let me know if it is possible to find children if multilevel inheritance is there?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are running a version of PostgreSQL with `RECURSIVE` support here's a function that finds derived tables for the specified base table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tables_derived_from(base_namespace name, base_table name)
RETURNS TABLE (table_schema name, table_name name, oid oid)
AS $BODY$
    WITH RECURSIVE inherited_id AS
    (
        SELECT i.inhrelid AS oid
        FROM pg_inherits i
        JOIN pg_class base_t ON i.inhparent = base_t.oid
        JOIN pg_namespace base_ns ON base_t.relnamespace = base_ns.oid
        WHERE base_ns.nspname = base_namespace AND base_t.relname = base_table

        UNION

        SELECT i.inhrelid AS oid
        FROM pg_inherits i
        JOIN inherited_id b ON i.inhparent = b.oid
    )
    SELECT child_ns.nspname as table_schema, child_t.relname as table_name, child_t.oid
    FROM inherited_id i
    JOIN pg_class child_t ON i.oid = child_t.oid 
    JOIN pg_namespace child_ns ON child_t.relnamespace = child_ns.oid
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that one table can inherit *multiple* tables, and none of the solutions listed really expose that; they just walk down the tree of a single parent. Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE a();
CREATE TABLE b();
CREATE TABLE ab_() INHERITS (a,b);
CREATE TABLE ba_() INHERITS (b,a);
CREATE TABLE ab__() INHERITS (ab_);
CREATE TABLE ba__() INHERITS (ba_);
CREATE TABLE ab_ba_() INHERITS (ab_, ba_);
CREATE TABLE ba_ab_() INHERITS (ba_, ab_);

WITH RECURSIVE inh AS (
        SELECT i.inhparent::regclass, i.inhrelid::regclass, i.inhseqno FROM pg_catalog.pg_inherits i WHERE inhparent = 'a'::regclass
        UNION
        SELECT i.inhparent::regclass, i.inhrelid::regclass, i.inhseqno FROM inh INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_inherits i ON (inh.inhrelid = i.inhparent)
) SELECT * FROM inh;
 inhparent | inhrelid | inhseqno 
-----------+----------+----------
 a         | ab_      |        1
 a         | ba_      |        2
 ab_       | ab__     |        1
 ba_       | ba__     |        1
 ab_       | ab_ba_   |        1
 ba_       | ab_ba_   |        2
 ba_       | ba_ab_   |        1
 ab_       | ba_ab_   |        2
(8 rows)
```

Notice that b doesn't show up at all *which is incorrect*, as both ab_ and ba_ inherit b.

I suspect the "best" way to handle this would be a column that's text[] and contains (array[inhparent::regclass])::text for each table. That would give you something like

```
inhrelid   path
ab_        {"{a,b}"}
ba_        {"{b,a}"}
ab_ba_     {"{a,b}","{b,a}"}
```

While obviously not ideal, that would at least expose the complete inheritance path and allow you to access it with enough gymnastics. Unfortunately, constructing that is not at all easy.

A somewhat simpler alternative is not to include the full inheritance path at each level, only each tables direct parents. That would give you this:

```
inhrelid    parents
ab_         {a,b}
ba_         {b,a}
ab_ba_      {ab_,ba_}
```