# function/procedure to update (ALTER) another function/procedure

Tags: function, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2, database-partitioning

I have partitioned tables on PostgreSQL 9.2 each and every one with a partition function that looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myPartitionSelectionFunction()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.PartitionColumn < DATE '2010-08-08 00:00:00') THEN INSERT INTO MyPartitionedTable_Week_31_2010 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF ( NEW.PartitionColumn < DATE '2010-08-15 00:00:00' AND NEW.PartitionColumn >=  DATE '2010-08-08 00:00:00') THEN INSERT INTO MyPartitionedTable_Week_32_2010 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'PartitionColumn out of range. Update myPartitionSelectionFunction()';
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

So, each week is a new partition. The problem is updating hundreds of functions every single week. I have to automate that, and a trigger for each insert isn't feasible. The idea is to create a function to be called by cron that updates each partition function, adding another ELSIF before the final ELSE. However I can't find a way to iterate through each function that has the "partition" name on it, then retrieve it's code (psql commands like \d won't work in a function, right?) to add the new ELSIF and update (ALTER) each function accordingly, cretaing a new partition in the process.

So, the biggest question I have now is:

How do I iterate (using cursor?) through each function once that has the "partition" name on it, then retrieve it's code, add another ELSIF before the ELSE and update (ALTER) it's contents not risking getting stuck in an infinite loop?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The query:
SELECT  proname, prosrc
FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
ON      pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE   nspname = 'public';
gets us the definition of the procedure/function.

Answer (score 4):

While you can retrieve function source from `pg_proc`, trying to retrieve it, edit it and update the function is a recipe for pain and suffering.

Instead, write a PL/PgSQL procedure that *generates the function text in its entirety*. Use a query against the `information_schema` or `pg_catalog.pg_class` to get the required table list, constraints, inheritance, etc. Loop over the query results, generating the body of the function, then join it all into a single block of text and pass it to `EXECUTE`.

Here's a toy example of one function generating another:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION very_meta(func_name text, message text) RETURNS void AS 
$$
DECLARE
    func_lines text;
BEGIN
    -- In reality you'd build this iteratively, or preferably use `string_agg` over
    -- a query, but I'm just going to supply a single line function body for this
    -- example:
    func_lines := format($LINE$RAISE NOTICE 'It works, message is %%!','%s';$LINE$, message);
    -- Now, build the function creation statement and execute it:
    EXECUTE format(
    $INNER$
        -- this is the SQL text we're going to execute, with the %%I placeholder
        -- to be replaced by the format(...) function:
        --
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %I() RETURNS void AS
        $INNERBODY$
        BEGIN
            -- and this is the body of the function we're generating
            -- in this case it's going to be substituted in as func_lines
            -- by format(...)
            %s
        END;
        $INNERBODY$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    $INNER$, func_name, func_lines);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Demo:

```
regress=> SELECT very_meta('lessmeta', 'Secret Message');
 very_meta 
-----------

(1 row)

regress=> SELECT lessmeta();
NOTICE:  It works, message is Secret Message!
 lessmeta 
----------

(1 row)
```

This can be combined with appropriate queries against `information_schema` and/or the system catalogs to get table lists, create the series of conditional tests, etc. [This answer I wrote a while ago details how to query the catalogs for inheritance relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12139506/398670), which might be useful, but you'll also need to identify the `CHECK` constraint in use. If you have a naming convention it might be simpler to just rely on that and a search of `pg_class`.

Do keep in mind that PostgreSQL's partitioning works best with at most a few hundred tables, if that. Performance will fall off significantly due to query planning cost with larger table counts.